# Liquibase table name prefix

Tags: liquibase

I'm currently developing a prototype for a Spring based plugin system. The idea is that plugins can use JPA entities and a liquibase changelog to maintain the database structure. In order to separate the tables created by plugins from the tables of the core system the plugins should be forced to use a prefix for table name.

For JPA/Hibernate that can be easily archived by using a naming strategy. But I've found no way to archive that for the liquibase changeset.

For example the plugin defines a changelog like follows

```
<changeSet id="2015-03-17-00-01" author="foo">
    <createTable tableName="fooentity">
        <column name="id" type="INT">
            <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false" />
        </column>
        <column name="name" type="VARCHAR(100)">
            <constraints nullable="false" />
        </column>
    </createTable>
</changeSet>
```

The table should be created with name "plugin_fooentity". The plugin itself should not know anything about the prefix since the prefix is given by the plugin/core system.

Would be great if someone can give me a hint for a possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use [`modifySql`](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/modify_sql.html) for this?

You would have to copy this to all changesets that you define but it should be possible.

It has a subtag called `regExpReplace` which you could use to define a general term like `create table (\w*?) .*` and replace this with `create table plugin_$1`.

Comment: This doesn't work...

    <modifySql>
            <regExpReplace  replace="create table (\w*?) .*"  with="create table tbl_$1"/>
     </modifySql>

Wrote this one...But doesn't get executed

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked like this:

**Using the modifySql statement**

I created 2 properties:

```
<property name="table.prefix" value="TBL_"/>
<property name="schema.name" value="PUBLIC"/>
```

Then added the following statements:

```
<modifySql>
    <regExpReplace replace="CREATE\ TABLE\ ${schema.name}.([\w]*)\ (.*)" with="CREATE TABLE ${schema.name}.${table.prefix}$1 $2"/>
</modifySql>

<modifySql>
    <regExpReplace replace="CREATE\ UNIQUE\ INDEX\ ${schema.name}.([\w]*)\ ON\ PUBLIC.([\w]*)\((.*)\)" with="CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ${schema.name}.$1 ON ${schema.name}.${table.prefix}$2($3)"/>
</modifySql>

<modifySql>
    <regExpReplace replace="CREATE\ INDEX\ ${schema.name}.([\w]*)\ ON\ ${schema.name}.([\w]*)\((.*)\)" with="CREATE INDEX ${schema.name}.$1 ON ${schema.name}.${table.prefix}$2($3)"/>
</modifySql>
```